# What's the Rails way to handle singular/plural possibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When you present a message to the user that involves an entity that could be either singular or plural, Rails has a shortcut to handle that. I'm talking about this situation:

"Delete committee? Its X meeting(s) will also be deleted."

Rails has a way so that "meeting" is presented as "meeting" or "meetings" depending on X.

I can't remember what that way is. It's not `String#pluralize`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper::pluralize(count, singular, plural = nil)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize)

> Attempts to [pluralize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) the `singular`
>   word unless `count` is 1. If `plural` is
>   supplied, it will use that when count
>   is > 1, otherwise it will use the
>   Inflector to determine the plural form

Examples:

```
  pluralize(1, 'person')
  # => 1 person

  pluralize(2, 'person')
  # => 2 people

  pluralize(3, 'person', 'users')
  # => 3 users

  pluralize(0, 'person')
  # => 0 people
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Rails 5**

```
'person'.pluralize(2)
# => people
```

Answer (score 1):

`pluralize` works for English, but not most other locales. To handle multiple locales, see [the documentation for locale-specific pluralizations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization)

Comment: For some real fun, see how plurals are different in Russian depending upon if the number ends in 1;2,3,4;5,6,7,8,9,0. http://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php